# Different results for displacement using different Kinematics equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

We drop an object from a height. It displaces a distance $L$ in the $\vec{y}$ direction.
So:
$$ L = \frac{1}{2}at^2 $$
Or:
$$ v^2-v_0^2 = 2aL \rightarrow L = \frac{v^2}{2a}$$

How much would the object have been displaced in the $\vec{y}$ direction if the magnitude of the acceleration $a$ had been twice as big?

Using the first equation the answer is: $2L$

However if we use the second equation the answer should be: $\frac{L}{2}$

Which one of the answers is correct?

Comment: You've assumed (I think) that $v$ and $t$ don't change when you change the acceleration. Can you justify this?

Comment: @or1426: I figure you could let the object fall for the same amount of time each time (such that it doesn't hit the ground with either acceleration), so $t$ can be the same in both cases.

Comment: @KyleKanos you can also let it fall until it reaches the same final velocity in each case. My point was that you *can't to both*.

Comment: @or1426: Also valid. You probably could expand your comment(s) a little bit and make an answer out of it(them).

Comment: @or1426 Sorry if the question was ambiguous. I didn't know we need to replace a new v in the second formula when we change the acceleration. If I knew that I wouldn't ask such a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is correct, $L_{new}=2L$.

In your second expression $L=\frac{v^2}{2a}$, when changing  $a$ you must also find a new end speed $v$,

$$L_{new}=\frac{v_{new}^2}{2a_{new}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{v_{new}^2}{2a}\neq\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{2a}=\frac{1}{2}L$$

**A note from reading the comments to the question:**

I am assuming the objects fall during the *same time* $t$ (not specified in the question). Then of course, with larger acceleration the final speed will be larger.

If instead the objects fall until reaching the *same velocity* $v$, then the *time* cannot be the same for both. You reach the wanted velocity faster with a larger acceleration. And then I am wrong; then your second expression would be the right one, and $L_{new}=\frac{1}{2}L$.